# Querying a table using SQL - columns

Tags: sql, filter

I am trying to query on a table. Let's say there 3 columns, color, car brand, and car model.

I want to exclude all blue and green colors cars, and no Honda Civic. This is the where statement I have below:

```
color not in ("blue", "green") 
and (carBrand not = "Honda" and carModel not = "Civic").
```

I tried using the above statement, and it actually excludes all Honda, all Civic, and exclude any color that is blue or green. I've decided to break the query into two pieces and running them in sequence below:

1. `color not in ("blue","green")`

   Then from that list run below:
2. `carBrand not ="Honda" and carModel not = "Civic"`

My question is, can I have done the above action with one query rather two queries.

FYI, I like Honda Civics, just thought it was a good example since a lot of people know that car model.

Thanks in advance.

---

Added new comments below for ease of reference.
I tried using the codes below. The code excludes the scenario of
Red,    Honda,  Accord. I have also added a sample table of the data for reference. Thanks for the help.

```
SELECT Color, CarBrand, CarModel
FROM ColorCarModel
WHERE (
(Color Not In ('green','blue'))
 AND (CarBrand Not In 'Honda') 
 AND (CarModel Not In 'Civic')
);
```

Example data:

```
ID  Color   CarBrand    CarModel
1   Green   Honda   Civic
2   Blue    Honda   Civic
3   Red Honda   Civic
4   Green   Ford    Civic
5   Blue    Ford    Taurus
6   Red Ford    Taurus
7   Red Honda   Accord
8   Red Ford    Explorer
```

Comment: Do you mean that all Hondas and all Civics should be excluded, or only those records with Honda and not Civic, or Civic and not Honda?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you wanted to exlude based on the 3 filters ... try this

where not (color in ('blue','green') and carBrand ='Honda' and carModel = 'Civic')

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Color, CarBrand, CarModel FROM YourTable
WHERE Color NOT IN ('green','blue') 
AND CarBrand NOT IN ('Honda') 
AND CarModel NOT IN ('Civic');

Try this and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I tried using the codes below, which should be the same as above. The code excludes the scenario of Red, Honda, Accord. I have also added a sample table of the data for reference. Thanks for the help.

SELECT Color, CarBrand, CarModel
FROM ColorCarModel
WHERE (
(Color Not In ('green','blue'))
 AND (CarBrand Not In 'Honda') 
AND (CarModel Not In 'Civic')
);


ID Color CarBrand CarModel
1 Green Honda Civic
2 Blue Honda Civic
3 Red Honda Civic
4 Green Ford Civic
5 Blue Ford Taurus
6 Red Ford Taurus
7 Red Honda Accord
8 Red Ford Explorer

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your original `where` clause is that you applied the `not in` operator **separately** to the populations of CarBrand and CarModel.  You had:

`(CarBrand Not In ("Honda")) and (CarModel Not In ("Civic"))`

Instead, you want:

`Not(CarBrand = "Honda" and CarModel = "Civic")`

Here is a working example:

```
data ColorCarModel;
    format id best. color $20. CarBrand $20. CarModel $20.;
    input id color CarBrand CarModel;
    datalines;
1   Green   Honda   Civic
2   Blue    Honda   Civic
3   Red     Honda   Civic
4   Green   Ford    Civic
5   Blue    Ford    Taurus
6   Red     Ford    Taurus
7   Red     Honda   Accord
8   Red     Ford    Explorer
9   Red     Dummy   Civic
run;

proc sql;
    select color, CarBrand, CarModel
    from ColorCarModel
    where (
        upcase(color) not in ('GREEN','BLUE') AND
        NOT (upcase(CarBrand) = 'HONDA' AND upcase(CarModel) = 'CIVIC')
    );
quit;
```

Notice also that I apply `upcase()` to the variables before comparing them to strings.  This prevents problems caused by mixed case in the data set (i.e. `where CarBrand = "Honda"` would miss observations where CarBrand contains "honda").

If it's easier to think about the logic without any nesting, the following SQL provides an equivalent filter via concatenation of CarModel and CarBrand:

```
proc sql;
    select color, CarBrand, CarModel
    from ColorCarModel
    where (
        upcase(color) not in ('GREEN','BLUE') AND
        upcase(catx('-', CarBrand, CarModel)) <> 'HONDA-CIVIC'
    );
quit;
```

Because these filters are essentially propositional logic, a good tutorial or text on that subject could be a helpful reference.  In particular, learning rules like De Morgan's law can help you think through how to transform a `where` clause to a different, equivalent form, which can be helpful in simplifying complex logic.  If you're feeling ambitious, [Discrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072899050) by Rosen is a standard text used in CS curricula that includes an early chapter on propositional logic.